# How to insert programmatically a new line in an Excel cell in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, aspose

I'm using the Aspose library to create an Excel document. Somewhere in some cell I need to insert a new line between two parts of the text.

I tried "\r\n" but it doesn't work, just displays two square symbols in cell. I can however press Alt+Enter to create a new line in that same cell.

How do I insert a new line programmatically?

Comment: are you using the right encoding? A .net string is UTF16 ...

Comment: I have no idea really. I'm just modifying someone else's code. Any way to encode a piece of string differently?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the Aspose Cells forums: [How to use new line char with in a cell?](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/163248/how-to-use-new-line-char-with-in-a-cell.aspx)

After you supply text you should set the cell's IsTextWrapped style to true

```
worksheet.Cells[0, 0].Style.WrapText = true;
```

Comment: received this exception: 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'IsTextWrapped'

Comment: Try with "worksheet.Cells[0, 0].Style.WrapText = true;" instead.

Answer (score 10):

```
cell.Text = "your firstline<br style=\"mso-data-placement:same-cell;\">your secondline";
```

If you are getting the text from DB then:

```
cell.Text = textfromDB.Replace("\n", "<br style=\"mso-data-placement:same-cell;\">");
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to insert the character code that Excel uses, which IIRC is 10 (ten).

---

**EDIT**: OK, here's some code. Note that I was able to confirm that the character-code used is indeed 10, by creating a cell containing:

> A
>
> B

...and then selecting it and executing this in the VBA immediate window:

```
?Asc(Mid(Activecell.Value,2,1))
```

So, the code you need to insert that value into another cell in VBA would be:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "A" & vbLf & "B"
```

(since vbLf is character code 10).

I know you're using C# but I find it's *much* easier to figure out what to do if you first do it in VBA, since you can try it out "interactively" without having to compile anything. Whatever you do in C# is just replicating what you do in VBA so there's rarely any difference. (Remember that the C# interop stuff is just using the same underlying COM libraries as VBA).

Anyway, the C# for this would be:

```
oCell.Value = "A\nB";
```

Spot the difference :-)

---

**EDIT 2**: Aaaargh! I just re-read the post and saw that you're using the Aspose library. Sorry, in that case I've no idea.

Comment: Well, U+000A is \n. But I think if that worked then inserting \r\n would have worked too, but would have left a square on the first cell.

Comment: I've never touched nor seen VBA, so I wouldn't be able to do it anyway. Thanks for you time anyway.

Comment: In the end I went with semicolon since a new line was an option not requirement. The issue is therefore closed.

Answer (score 4):

Internally Excel uses U+000D U+000A (CR+LF, `\r\n`) for a line break, at least in its XML representation. I also couldn't find the value directly in a cell. It was migrated to another XML file containing shared strings. Maybe cells that contain line breaks are handled differently by the file format and your library doesn't know about this.

Comment: It seems that CRLF works fine in Excel 2010, but leads to the unprintable character box being displayed in earlier versions. It seems that using just "\n" (LF) is required for compatibility with older versions of Excel.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested in the Infragistics solution, here it is.

1. Use

   `Environment.NewLine`
2. Make sure your cell is wrapped

   `dataSheet.Rows[i].Cells[j].CellFormat.WrapText = ExcelDefaultableBoolean.True;`

Comment: ExcelDefaultableBoolean.True  there is no such thing.

Comment: @hakan : I had no problem finding and using ExcelDefaultableBoolean.True,  perhaps it's a version thing with Infragistics?  It wouldn't be the first time they changed something.

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) does it this way:

```
        IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
        IRange a1 = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["A1"];
        a1.Value = "Hello\r\nWorld!";
        a1.WrapText = true;
        workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\HelloWorld.xlsx", FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
```

Note the "WrapText = true" - Excel will not wrap the text without this. I would assume that Aspose has similar APIs.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

"\n" works fine. If the input is coming from a multi-line textbox, the new line characters will be "\r\n", if this is replaced with "\n", it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using PEAR 'Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer' and 'OLE':

Only way I could get "`\n`" to work was making the cell `$format->setTextWrap();`  and then using "`\n`" would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chr(13).  Then just wrap the whole thing in Chr(34).  Chr(34) is double quotes.

- VB.Net Example:
- TheContactInfo = ""
- TheContactInfo = Trim(TheEmail) & chr(13)
- TheContactInfo = TheContactInfo & Trim(ThePhone) & chr(13)
- TheContactInfo = Chr(34) & TheContactInfo & Chr(34)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
worksheet.Cells[0, 0].Style.WrapText = true;
worksheet.Cells[0, 0].Value = yourStringValue.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
```

My issue was that the \r\n came escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
E.Run runForBreak = new E.Run();

E.Text textForBreak = new E.Text() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
textForBreak.Text = "\n";
runForBreak.Append(textForBreak);
sharedStringItem.Append(runForBreak);
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. That's especially useful here since there are already twelve other answers; what sets your approach apart from them? Can I ask that you update your question with additional details?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it is really simple.

You may edit an xml version of excel. Edit a cell to give it new line between your text, then save it. Later you may open the file in editor, then you will see a new line is represented by 
`&#10;`

Have a try....

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried "\n" I guess, it should work.