# Excel line break within same cell?

Tags: php, excel

Can someone tell me how to simply make a line break within the same cell when exporting a .xls file using PHP? I've tried with \n, \t, \r, but none of them seems to work.

My code is short and simple:

```
ob_end_clean();
$filename ="test_doc.xls";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo "I\nWANT\nTHIS\nTO\nBE\nWITHIN\nTHE\nSAME\nCELL";
exit;
```

Comment: have you tried \r\n ?

Comment: @MightyPork Just tried it, doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you open the output and select the cell, do you get new lines in the formula bar? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1177801/212869

Comment: Depends if you actually want to write a real BIFF-format Excel file or simply a csv file

Comment: `echo "\"I\nWANT\nTHIS\nTO\nBE\nWITHIN\nTHE\nSAME\nCELL\"";`

Comment: @AxelRichter worked, then comes the other question: how do i get out from the cell?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your "other" question right, but maybe `echo "\"I\nWANT\nTHIS\nTO\nBE\nWITHIN\nTHE\nSAME\nCELL\"\t\"Next Cell\"\t1234";`?